# how to measure / quantify "sluggishness" in a Corona SDK game app?

Tags: ios, performance, box2d, coronasdk

How to measure / quantify "sluggishness" in a Corona SDK game app?

I am seeking some performance issues on older phone (e.g. iPhone 4, Samsung GT-I9000) on a Corona SDK based physics game I have built (which uses Box2D).  They work but are a little sluggish and not snappy in responsiveness.  I have tried logging the FPS (frames per sec), Memory and Texture memory however these figures look ok and don't seem to help quantify the sluggishness.  For example the frame rate didn't drop below 30 FPS which is the default.

Do I need to put timestamps through out the main game loop to see where it spends it's time for example.  However if the frame rate is NOT dropping then doesn't this imply there shouldn't be an issue as the game is managing to complete the game loop in the required time to keep the framerate at it required level?

So I'm ultimately trying to work out whether what I'm seeing is "normal" or not and whether as such I can release now (versus having to spend more time trying to get the game more snappy on older phones)

Memory figures for the game are below which are ok I think:

```
- Model  / fps / memory / texture_memory
 - iPhone: 30, 1811kB, 9.6MB
 - iPhone5: 30, 1874kB, 34MB
 - iPad Retina, 30, 1800kb, 119MB
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using something like [Corona Profiler](http://www.mydevelopersgames.com/site/). It's not free ($10), but if you use Corona regularly it's money well spent.

It does exactly what you've just asked: it tells you how long each function is taking, and how much memory is uses up. 
It helped me by pointing out that I'd nested a few loops without realising, which took the time for the function down to about 15% of what it had previously been. You could write the functions to do this yourself I suppose, but personally I'd rather spend the $10 and get back to writing my game instead.